# Python Pyramid Learning Resource

Tags: python, pyramid

I have trid learning the framework with the help of the book, [The Pyramid Web Application Development Framework](http://static.pylonsproject.org/pyramid-1.1.pdf). I have somewhat managed to understand up-to URL Dispatch. But I still find it difficult to grab some concepts.

Can you lead me to some easy-for-newbie tutorials? Do I need previous experience of other web frameworks?

Comment: For a video tutorial click [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/web-applications-with/9781771374361/).
For a written tutorial and example code use this [link](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-blogr/en/latest/) provides well documented project with tutorial, everything you need to build medium sized applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try #pyramid, they are set of nice people, they helped me out, when I was struggling.

Comment: The folks at the pylons-discuss google group are super friendly and helpful!  You should definitely consider posting any questions you have there.  I asked about Traversal topics and they replied almost immediately.  The url is:  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/pylons-discuss

Comment: @Kracekumar, sorry for getting back on this question. But I was searching for REST API tutorial with pyramid, can you suggest some good links. Please

Answer (score 14):

I've been doing web dev for > 15 years, and > 10 with Python, and I found some of the concepts in Pyramid hard to understand, too.

I'd suggest just pushing through; copy-n-paste if you have to, and keep on working. I'm noticing that concepts are 'gelling' for me after the fact, and what I used to find confusing I now take for granted. Perhaps the ideas merely need to soak in?

The organization of the code, and its founding philosophies are somewhat more abstract and perhaps therefore more difficult than I am used to from other frameworks, but I am really enjoying the flexibility. In particular, there seems to always be like 5 ways to do something, all of equal merit, when in Python we are used to having some ways more "blessed" than others.

It just a lot to wrap your head around. So, I suppose my short-term suggestion is not to try. Just build some things, ask questions when you get stuck, and be comfortable with the discomfort of not knowing how every little bit of Pyramid works...

I would also recommend that you resist the urge to take its flexibility as an opportunity to force it to behave more like some other system(s) that you may be familiar with... don't build a translation layer on top. Then you'll be fighting the code rather than getting your work done, and you'll end up deeper into the guts than you might want to be at this point.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, there are no other Pyramid books on the market.  You might want to skim the "cookbook" at http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/dev/ though.  And as kracekumar said, joining the #pyramid IRC channel on freenode.net is a good idea.

Comment: nice to have the author himself replying. Thank you for the book :)

Answer (score 5):

### Try: [Pyramid Single File Tasks Tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/single_file_tasks/single_file_tasks.html)

I encountered the same scenario, I was able to finish reading the **URL Dispatch** section but wasn't really able to understand a thing. Usually, when we become stuck on situations like this, we easily give up and immediately try another one *(framework)*. But because I'm a Pyramid zealot (or I should say *fan* eversince) I resisted the switch.

So I went back to the Pyramid homepage and thought of looking on *cookbooks*. Then I saw this [Pyramid Single File Tasks Tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/single_file_tasks/single_file_tasks.html). To my surprise, I've managed to understand some concepts quickly by simply following the steps and looking at the codes.

If you're still into Pyramid, I would suggest skipping the *URL Dispatch* section for now and experiment with this tutorial first until you become comfortable with it, then continue with the docs later on.

Happy programming ^^,

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using Google, and the Pylons mailing list.

I tried to learn TurboGears, another Python web framework, and was told to buy the book. I bought the book, then they changed the API significantly so that my purchase was pointless. They're still changing it today.

Pyramid is not Turbogears - but it's based on the wisdom of other frameworks, each of which had their own methods, many of which have now changed to become Pyramid. And they may change again.

So, as much as I would like to recommend that you support book authors in their glorious quest to bring you commercial-quality documentation, software libraries and frameworks (and the projects that use them) evolve so quickly that I think the internet will remain the best way to learn about them, at least until they are very mature.